# Backpack vs handheld blower for cleaning driveways

Tags: mowing, equipment

I have a (very) small mowing business, I do about 6 lawns. My blower died the very last time I needed it last year(perfect timing!) and now that its starting to get a bit warmer I am looking for a new one. I previously had a cheap handheld, but I was wondering how much it would benefit me to have a backpack. It would only really be used to clean residential driveways, small patios and the street in front of the house after mowing. Would a backpack be good, or would it be worse because of the size and extra time it takes to put it on?
Thanks!

Comment: It depends how you buy your tools, are you a buy quality, maintain and use many years or buy cheap and get a new one when it breaks?

Comment: Many lawn service companies work our area ; I would estimate about 3/4  use backpacks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your experience with the hand-held blower and your future plan regarding your business expansion.

*The points for having a backpack blower:*

- A more ergonomic design compared to handheld blowers would cause less fatigue of hands.
- Being more powerful, would require less time for the completion of work.
- The above two points play positively if you plan to expand your business.

*The points against having a backpack blower:*

- More expensive to buy compared to a hand-held blower, may cost even ten times a handheld blower. Uses more fuel.
- Needs to adjust power of blowing while operating on a narrow area so as not to blow the debris to a neighbor's property.
- Heavier and bulky compared to a handheld blower.
- You have already used a handheld blower, and so you are more familiar with it.

In summary, a backpack blower may be considered only if you have suffered significant and painful fatigue in your hands while using the handheld blower, and you are planning to considerably expand your business, because the backpack blower may cost 5-10 times a handheld blower, and also consumes more fuel.